Explain this method for generating Mersenne Primes based on Lagrange interpolation
This question is about the work A Method for Generating Mersenne Primes and the Extent of the Sequence of the Even Perfect Numbers.
In the 3rd section you will read:

I don't understand understand formula 3.4.
Can someone explain it?
Note: the overlined $N$ ($\overline N$ in the summatory) appears in section 2:
If Goldbach conjecture is valid:
$\exists q_1 \exists q_2$ such that $2N=q_1 + q_2$ $\implies$ $\exists \overline q_1 \exists \overline q_2$ such that $2\overline N=\overline q_1 - \overline q_2$,
with $\overline N < N$ and all $q_1, q_2, \overline q_1,\overline q_2$ primes

I am confused. As far as I know , there is no efficient method to find new Mersenne primes. The last record holds for about six years , so there seems to be no shortcut. The even perfect numbers have a $1-1$ correspondence , so to extend the set of known even perfect numbers is the same as to extend the set of known Mersenne primes. We can interpolate the Mersenne primes only if we know them.

$3.4$ looks a bit odd.  It's trivially true, as any multiple of $p'$ can be written as sum of powers of $p'$ (or just as a multiple of $p'$), but without saying something more than that, it's hard to see the point.  Have the $K_{2i}$ been defined elsewhere?

I am so confused as you, @Peter.  After seeing your comment I remembered another preprint: Generation and Distribution of Prime Numbers Using a Modified Lagrange Polynomial which "presents a PRIME-GENERATING algorithm based on a 1-degree polynomial that can generate prime
numbers from CONSECUTIVE primes".

Replying your comment based on the preprint Generation and Distribution of Prime Numbers Using a Modified Lagrange Polynomial: "We can interpolate the Mersenne primes ONLY if we know them":

I think there is an UNUSUAL ideia going on the work A Method for Generating Mersenne Primes and the Extent of the Sequence of the Even Perfect Numbers and it is possible to INTERPOLATE old Mersenne primes and discover new ones, though not efficiently.

We can only ESTIMATE where the new exponents might lie , but that's it. We still must "make our hands dirty" if we want to find them.

We do not even know any algorithm to find ANY new huge prime without applying a probable-prime test (after establishing the candidates with sieving of course) , so I heavily doubt that this method holds some water , unless the procedure is so inefficient that we can apply the primality test anyway.
